# How can I protect a pdf file signed with iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm signing a pdf document with iTextSharp. It works fine, but I want to protect this file, I want that this pdf signed can not be printed, copied or signed again, how can I do it?

I have tried with

```
PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(
    reader,
    new FileStream(this.outputPDF, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write),
    true,
    null,
    null,
    PdfWriter.AllowFillIn | PdfWriter.AllowScreenReaders);
```

but doesnt work, it says

> iTextSharp.text.DocumentException: 'The original document was reused. Read it again from file.'

```cs
public void Sign(string SigReason, string SigContact, string SigLocation, bool visible)
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(this.inputPDF);
/*ERROR-->*/PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, new FileStream(this.outputPDF, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write), true, null, null, PdfWriter.AllowFillIn | PdfWriter.AllowScreenReaders);
            PdfStamper st = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, new FileStream(this.outputPDF, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write), '\0', null, true);
            st.MoreInfo = this.metadata.getMetaData();
            st.XmpMetadata = this.metadata.getStreamedMetaData();
            PdfSignatureAppearance sap = st.SignatureAppearance;

            sap.SetCrypto(this.myCert.Akp, this.myCert.Chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED);
            sap.Reason = SigReason;
            sap.Contact = SigContact;
            sap.Location = SigLocation;

            if (visible)
                sap.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(100, 100, 250, 150), 1, null);

            st.Close();

        }
```

Comment: It still does not work with the change you've made


Hello Amedee,It still does not work with the change you've made. Its Says:
``iTextSharp.text.DocumentException: 'The original document was reused. Read it again from file.'´´
or
´´System.IO.IOException: 'The process can not access the file 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.pdf' because it is being used in another process.
'´´

Comment: Please share the stack trace of the exception.